# Python: call class instance outside function

Tags: python, class, module

I am creating a script for measurements which I'd like to tidy up for readability of the end-users. The script communicates with all kinds of equipment, which are loaded as separate classes. For the purpose of this question, I created a dummy instrument, which is saved in a separate file (as is the case for the actual program I'm building as well):

**instruA.py**

```py
class instruA:
    def msg(self):
        return 123
```

Because the main measurement script - the file that the end-user changes - should be as simple as possible, I created a 'lab' module that hosts the measurement commands:

**lab.py**

```py
import sys

meas_dict = {}

def str_to_class(classname):
    return getattr(sys.modules[__name__], classname)
```

The user would only change the main script (shown below) to add all the devices that he wants to use for measurements, after which the scripts take care of the rest. The script for this question looks like this:

**main.py**

```py
from instruA import *
a = instruA()

# Create a list of devices that needs to be measured 
# (typically: 'a.msg, foo.bar, b.somevariable')
meas_dict = 'a.msg'

# Load lab software        
import lab
lab.meas_dict = meas_dict

# TEST LINE OF CODE (GIVES ERROR):
lab.str_to_class('a')
```

I would expect the script to point me to the right object, i.e. `<instruA.instruA at 0x1b2ba7d1e80>`. Instead, it gives `module 'lab2' has no attribute 'a'`.

How can I make sure that my *lab.py* has access to my class instances?

Answer (score 0):

This is unclear what you want to do and it is hard to guess your files structure. But where you have `getattr(str_to_class(dev[0]), dev[1])` you are not retrieving the proper key from `meas_dict`.

I think if you change that part to the way it was before (in `lab.py` file), it will work fine.

Like this:

```py
import sys

meas_dict = {}

def measure(md=None):
    if md is None:
        md = meas_dict

    md = md.split(',')
    for device in md:
        cls = md[dev]['dev'], variable = md[dev]['var']
        meas_cmd = getattr(cls, variable)
        print(meas_cmd())
``
```

Comment: I have tried to restructure my question to improve its clarity. Your previous answer did not fix it - your remark that I'm not retrieving the proper key is true, but this is the reason for me to post this question. Hopefully my edited version can show you what I really want.